# Unable to establish remote connection: Neo4jError: WebSocket connection failure. Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

I have neo4j installed on https://104.128.65.247:7474/browser (Ubuntu 20.04 and neo4j version 4.3.6)
but it is refusing to connect
I have uncommented dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
even changed dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687 to dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:0.0.0.0:7687 (tested both doesn't work)
Both 7474 AND 7687 ports are assessable from any where (using uwf)
I even trying disabling uwf
nothing works
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How are you running Neo4j?  (i.e Desktop, command line, Docker, etc.)

Comment: Command line works (on the server)
I was trying to connect with neo4j desktop on my system (not server)

Comment: Can you verify from your desktop with netcat? nc -z -v 104.128.65.247 7474 and  nc -z -v 104.128.65.247 7687

Comment: Start with only setting dbms.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0 and get that to work, then add your ssl conf (i.e. hold off with using https:// until you have successfully used http://). Also the default port for https is 7473 and not 7474.

Comment: Also, you may want to set dbms.default_advertised_address=104.128.65.247